# Update a field in other records based on the value of same field in a record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to transfer the **contents (value) of a field** in an Access form **by VBA** to previous and next records in same form, while I am still in the current record. **Could be said I want to copy it to the same field but into other records same time.**

For example, a worker has several different records in a form specific to himself in a database. If his working hours changed in a record, the working hours stored in a field must be transferred to other records automatically.

I mean, a worker has a work table **with 29 records**. I want all records be automatically updated when an employee's hours on a record change. For example, **when record number 17** in a form changes in the **"working time" field**, then the **same field in other records (from record No. 1 to No. 16 and then from No. 18 to No. 29)** will updated automatically.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank You

Comment: Sure, but it won't be simple. Why would multiple records have same value? Sounds like poorly structured schema. Data in a record dependent on data in another record is bad design. Edit question to show sample data as formatted text table.

Comment: Yes. Store the _start time_ only and, when needed, calculate the working hours as the duration between this and the start time of the next record. This way, adjusting the start time of one task will automatically increase/decrease the duration of the previous and the next task.

Comment: In answer to your question: Why would multiple records have same value?
I have to say that multiple records do not have the same value, but each record has numbers identical fields that are repeated in other records! Like millions of forms in thousands of other Access programs!
Like the example I gave:

Comment: A worker has a work table with 29 records. I want all records be automatically updated when an employee's hours on a record change. For example, when record number 17 in a form changes in the "working time" field, then the same field in other records (from record No. 1 to No. 16 and then from No. 18 to No. 29) will updated automatically.

Comment: You said "working hours stored in a field must be transferred to other records automatically" - to me that reads as saving same value to multiple records. I still do not understand your data. Edit question to show sample. Again, saving data dependent on other data is usually a bad idea, especially when that other data is in another record.